# appending child div to its parent dynamically in the constructor

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I'm having issues using appendchild() to append a div within a div. If possible, I would like to avoid using jquery.I'm using constructor functions for both the parent and child divs.

```
<script>

    var loopi = 0;


    function codeDiv(){
        codeDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
        codeDiv1.style.height  = "100px";
        codeDiv1.style.width = "200px";
        codeDiv1.style.border = "thick solid black";

    }

    function functionObject(){
        var functionDivObject = document.createElement("div");
        functionDivObject.style.width = "500px";
        functionDivObject.style.height = "500px";
        functionDivObject.style.border = "thick solid black";
        document.body.appendChild(functionDivObject);
        var codeDiv1 = new codeDiv();
        functionDivObject.appendChild(codeDiv1);  //I am having the problem here
        functionDivObject.id = "functionDiv"+loopi;
        loopi++;
    }
    loopi = 0;


    var temp = new functionObject();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser console should have an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`, since the [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method needs a dom element reference as its argument.

In your case you are passing a `codeDiv` instance to it.

You need to return the new div from `codeDiv`

```
function codeDiv() {
    var codeDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
    codeDiv1.style.height = "100px";
    codeDiv1.style.width = "200px";
    codeDiv1.style.border = "thick solid black";
    return codeDiv1;

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pgtuvo9a/)

Comment: Worth mentioning that there does not appear to be any reason for the OP to be using `new` at all.  These are just functions, not constructors because there's no instance data or methods.

Comment: Why do we not need the new? is it because we are returning the element from the function? @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

```
function codeDiv() {
    var codeDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
    codeDiv1.style.height = "100px";
    codeDiv1.style.width = "200px";
    codeDiv1.style.border = "thick solid black";
    return codeDiv1;

}

   function functionObject(){
        var functionDivObject = document.createElement("div");
        functionDivObject.style.width = "500px";
        functionDivObject.style.height = "500px";
        functionDivObject.style.border = "thick solid black";
        document.body.appendChild(functionDivObject);
        var codeDiv1 = codeDiv();  // call function which is returning div node
        functionDivObject.appendChild(codeDiv1);  //I am having the problem here
        functionDivObject.id = "functionDiv"+loopi;
        loopi++;
    }
```